# Ambiguity of publishing as an undergrad

Tags: soft-question, solution-verification, publishing

After many grueling and tedious hours of learning LaTeX and the formatting of math papers, and reading countless papers on arXiv, I'm finally left with a reasonable draft for a proof that I'd hope to see published. At such point, I realized I had no clue on what the process of publication was. Hence, I asked my friend, Shawn, what the process was like for his field (being in microbiology), and if an undergrad could publish as a sole-author. His response:

> In my field, papers must be co-signed by a faculty-appointed supervisor.

Without one, I  reached out to the mathematics professors to see if any were interested in co-signing and for more info on the general process. Their response:

> Independent research as an undergrad is not common, but if the results are interesting enough, then you can publish  as the sole author.

I then explained what the paper was about, (proving the existence of a closed-formed function for [Conway's base-13 function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function) over certain domains), and he told me:

> That does seem plausibly interesting, the first step (after formatting a final version) would be to upload the proof to [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/).

Thankfully, having a university domain for an email grants be the ability to do so. After exhausting the help of all the professors that had time for me, I'm still left with a few questions.

With the professors at my university justifiably busy, **are there resources for having someone proof-read my paper?**

After arXiv, **what would the following steps be?**

Any additional information would be hugely appreciated.

**Edit:** I'm aware that, intuitively, different journals publish material on different subjects. A problem is, with not having a large vocabulary for mathematical terminology, I'm not sure what area of math my results fall under.

Comment: There is no requirement to "co-sign" a maths paper. To publish you just have to submit to a journal; most are online. Journals will typically ask you to use their LaTeX style files, but for some that is only a requirement after acceptance. Beware, there are predatory "pay-to-publish" journals out there. Avoid them.

Comment: It's strange that your professors are too busy to work with you on such a substantial and interesting project. Usually,  or at least often, when a student takes this level of initiative, professors respond positively. Are you sure there are no math professors at your university who'd be willing to proofread it for you?

Comment: @littleO To be a fair I've only emailed those with listed interests in somewhat related areas. Of those dozen-or-so I emailed, only one got back to me. There are still a few more I could reach out to. Regardless, I'm happy to hear that my topic seems interesting!

Comment: Maybe you could try asking professors whose classes you've taken, if you haven't already. They'll know you so they might be more likely to help (especially if you did great in their class). If they don't have the right background, they might themselves ask another professor to take a look at your draft, and that could be more likely to get a response.

Comment: There is a number of [mathematical undergraduate research journals](https://unl.libguides.com/c.php?g=51642&p=333916). Some require faculty sponsorship, others do not. Go to their websites and look at submission guidelines, which are usually linked in the menu on the home page.

Comment: I agree with @littleO that the first (and to me totally obvious, but then I grew up before email and such) step would be to talk to some professors you've taken classes under. Also, are there other professors who the local [grapevine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grapevine_(gossip)) suggests would be helpful to approach, even if they don't know you at all? When I was a student it was fairly common for students to gossip about these kinds of things.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thanks gentlemen, I will definitely reach out to some of my past professors. I have yet to really accumulate a repertoire with anyone in the math community.